# Is there a way to loop through a complete Databricks notebook (pySpark)?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Let’s take an example. I’m working on a large dataset and want to substrat my treatment on a weekly basis. My process is divided in multiple chunks / command for now.

My question is, is it possible to loop on all the notebook or should I regroup all my code/treatment in the same chunk ?

For instance, working on January 2021. I want to make the code run on a weekly bases, giving him the `starting date`, running from this date to `day+7`, apply all the treatment and store the results, update my `start` variable from `day+8` and this until it reach the limit fixed, for instance 31-January.

Is there a way to do it without regrouping all of the code in the same chunk? as a « `run all above` // `all below` command in line ? »

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this by changing your notebook to accept parameter(s) via [widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html), and then you can trigger this notebook, for example, as Databricks job or using `dbutils.notebook.run` from another notebook that will implement loop ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)), passing necessary dates as parameters.

This will be:

- in your original notebook:

```py
starting_date = dbutils.widgets.get("starting_date")
.... your code
```

- in the calling notebook (60 is timeout, could be higher depending on the amount of transformations):

```py
dbutils.notebook.run("path_to_orginal_notebook", 60, 
   {"starting_date": "2021-01-01"})
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn’t though about using another notebook to run this one !

Comment: There is a typo in you answare. It is dbutils.notebook.run(...) https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#language-python